# JNDI lookup of a datasource in JBoss 7.0.2 resulting in a NameNotFoundException

Tags: jboss, jndi

I'm having some issues getting a JNDI lookup of a datasource in JBoss 7.0.2 to work properly.  Basically, this application is one that should be deployable across multiple application servers, so I'd like to adhere to appropriate standards.  The application in question is a simple portlet application deployed in Liferay 6.1 running in a Jboss managed domain; I've tried various combinations of naming conventions in web.xml, jboss-web.xml, and persistence.xml; all to no avail.  My current configuration looks like this:

Spring persistence.xml:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="surveyDS" jndi-name="jdbc/surveyDS" resource-ref="true" />
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4">
    ...
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/surveyDS</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.4//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/surveyDS</res-ref-name>
        <jndi-name>java:jboss/datasources/surveyDS</jndi-name>
    </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>
```

Datasource definition in ${JBOSS_HOME}/domain/configuration/domain.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/surveyDS" pool-name="TestDSPool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
    <connection-url>****</connection-url>
    <driver>com.mysql</driver>
    <pool>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>****</user-name>
        <password>****</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

Deploying the portlet application works just fine; however, when I attempt to actually view the portlet, I get the following exception:

```
15:10:05,493 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/survey-portlets].[surveydisplay Servlet]] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-3) Servlet.service() for servlet surveydisplay Servlet threw exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/surveyDS -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.surveyDS
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:87)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:47)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:209)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392) [:1.6.0_26]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187) [org.springframework.context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
[ ... stack truncated for brevity ]
```

I feel like I must be missing something very simple and obvious at this point, but I have no idea what it might be.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Change the DataSource jndi-name in the JBoss `domain.xml` file to `java:jdbc/surveyDS`, and you should be fine.